# How to compare objects of two arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I had taken two arrays in JavaScript

```
arr1 = ["empid","Name"];

arr2 = [{"keyName":"empid" ,"keyValue":"2"}]
```

And I want to check the value of keyName should be any one element from arr1.

Comment: `arr2.map(({keyName}) => arr1.includes(keyName))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) short-circuits after finding the first match so it doesn't necessarily have to iterate over the whole array of objects. And it also returns a boolean which satisfies your use-case.

```js
const query1 = ['empid','Name'];
const arr1 = [{'keyName':'empid' ,'keyValue':'2'}];
const query2 = ['empid','Name'];
const arr2 = [{'keyName':'empid2' ,'keyValue':'five'}];
const query3 = ['empid','Name', 'test'];
const arr3 = [{'keyName':'test2' ,'keyValue':'five'},{'keyName':'test' ,'keyValue':'five'}];

function found(arr, query) {
  return arr.some(obj => {
    return query.includes(obj.keyName);
  });
}

console.log(found(arr1, query1));
console.log(found(arr2, query2));
console.log(found(arr3, query3));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `_.isEqual(object, other);`
It may help you.